# Julia convert String to Char, or convert Array{SubString{String},1} to char

Tags: string, char, julia

I want to convert an array of SubStrings into either Char or String values.

I split a String to get an array of elements fine

```
mdSplit = split(mdSub,r"[ ]+")
4-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "73"
 "G" 
 "T" 
 ""
```

but now I want to iterate through this array, and if the value is a character I'm going convert that character to a Char, or make a copy of it as a char
 have tried both convert and parse

```
convert(Char,string(mdSplit[2]))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you might want to reconsider whether you *really* want an array of String and Char. Isn't it nicer to have an array with only one element type?

Anyway, you can convert a SubString to a String or Char like this:

```
function string_or_char(s::SubString)
    length(s) == 1 && return first(s)
    return String(s)
end
```

Note that this function is type unstable. Then put it in an array like this:

```
arr = Union{Char,String}[]
for i in split_string
    push!(arr, string_or_char(i))
end
```

Alternatively, you can make your array like this:
`[string_or_char(s) for s in split_string]`. But this will be type unstable itself, and can return any of `Vector{Char}`, `Vector{String}` or `Vector{Any}`.

Comment: I dont' really want an array at all, I'm looping through it and converting the items to characters if they can be, which I'm then using for BioSequences to make them into DNA_nucleotides, the question was a bit unclear. I just wanted a Char

Answer (score 6):

`only()` seems to be the right way:

```
julia> string_a = "a"
"a"

julia> char_a = only(string_a)
'a': ASCII/Unicode U+0061 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
```

others solutions:

`mdSplit[2][1]` or `mdSplit[2][end]` or `first(mdSplit[2])` or `last(mdSplit[2])`

All change a 1 size String to a Char.

Answer (score 0):

Got there eventually

```
collect(mdSplit[2])[1]
```